# Creating spreadsheet with OpenXML format column as text

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

Creating a spreadsheet utilizing OpenXML, how do I format all the columns as text?

I have created a spreadsheet utilizing OpenXML. No issue, all is working fine, but the columns (which the user will fill in) are things like account numbers and the leading zeros are important.

Worksheet is created:

```
    private WorksheetPart InitializeSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetDocument doc, string sheetName)
    {
        // check if this document already has a workbook. this can happen if we've opened an existing document.
        if (doc.WorkbookPart == null)
        {
            doc.AddWorkbookPart();

            doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        }

        if (doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets == null)
            doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        var worksheet = doc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

        worksheet.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

        int sheetIndex = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Count() + 1;

        var sheet = new Sheet
        {
            Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheet),
            SheetId = (uint)sheetIndex,
            Name = sheetName
        };

        doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Append(sheet);

        return worksheet;
    }
```

Rows are populated:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            CustomerMatchingColumns key = columns.ElementAt(i).Key;

            string value = columns.ElementAt(i).Value ?? string.Empty;

            if (value.Length > maxColumnWidths[key])
                maxColumnWidths[key] = value.Length;

            var cell = new Cell();

            cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;

            Run cellProperties = new Run();

            cellProperties.Append(new Text(value));

            cellProperties.RunProperties = new RunProperties();

            CellFormat format = new CellFormat();

            // only bold the first row of our sheet. can pull this into a method param if needed
            if (rowIndex == 1)
                cellProperties.RunProperties.Append(new Bold());

            var inlineString = new InlineString();

            inlineString.Append(cellProperties);

            cell.Append(inlineString);

            row.InsertAt(cell, i);
        }
```

I would like to set every column on the spreadsheet to the equivalent of Category:Text.

Thanks,
Sammer

Comment: This code doesn't set any cell values. Post the relevant code please. Did you set a string or numeric value?  Libraries like Epplus at least will store a string as text, even if it looks as a string

Comment: Question updated to include code where cell values are being set.